# CASE statement with window function

Tags: sql, case, window-functions

**Table**

[image: Table]

Could someone assist I am looking for a solution to get the counts correct for each store item pair.
The first count is easy

`COUNT (*) OVER(PARTITION BY store ORDER BY s.deptitemcode DESC) StoreItemSeqNo`

However for the 2nd count, I only want the count if the Flag is true for each store item pair if the flag is false then the count should be the previous value if there was no previous value it should be zero.

Refer to table example

Comment: Post actual in text and desired results.  You requirement is not clear to me.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: What do you mean with "get the counts correct". What do you consider a "correct" count? You should **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: Maybe the first count is easy but pretty sure it is wrong.  Did you test this?  Is this homework?

Answer (score 10):

Aggregate functions can instead of `*` also take an expression. If `COUNT(..)` is called for an expression and not `*`, it counts everything except `NULL`. So, to count according to `flag`:

```
COUNT (CASE WHEN flag = 1 THEN flag ELSE NULL END) OVER(PARTITION BY store ORDER BY s.deptitemcode DESC) StoreItemSeqNo
```